# How to submit a form on enter when the textarea has focus?

Tags: html, forms

When filling out a form's textarea, the default behavior when the enter key is hit is to move to the next line. How can I change the behavior of the form so it will submit upon user hitting enter even when the user is in a textarea?

I used Firebug to checkout Stack Overflow's comment textarea (which has this behaviour), but couldn't see any JavaScript that achieved this affect. Is there a way to change the behavior of the textarea without using JavaScript?

Comment: What if we rename this question to "submit form on enter when in textarea"?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can't do this without JavaScript. Stackoverflow is using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) JavaScript library which attachs functions to HTML elements on page load.

Here's how you could do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
<textarea onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea>
```

Keycode 13 is the enter key.

Here's how you could do it with jQuery like as Stackoverflow does:

```
<textarea class="commentarea"></textarea>
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.commentarea').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
            event.preventDefault();
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Since users are more familiar with actions when they release the key, is a better practice to use onkeyup or keyup() instead of keydown().

Comment: Nice explanation. @Eric Fortis - good point about the onkeyup.

Comment: I will write a function an put it in my form functions file though to try and keep the code clean.

Comment: This answer works like a charm! This is one case where I think vanilla javascript is so much easier to implement than the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: As a sidenote, doing `this.form.submit()` will not trigger any event listeners you may have, nor will it run the code in the form's onsubmit attribute. In order to trigger these events you would want to call `this.form.requestSubmit()`

Answer (score 7):

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="textbox" id="field"/>
    <input type="button" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#field").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                document.myform.submit();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Notice the relevant part of the HTML is the ID, I used a textbox but it can be any tag you want to attach the behavior.  Also for readability I prefer to invoke the form by its ID as shown, this is very handy specially if you have multiple forms in your code.

Comment: nice, im not planing on learning jquery at the moment though. I prefer to write the function myself because then I get the chance to practice of writing javascript

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want a textarea to submit when you hit enter?

A "text" input will submit by default when you press enter. It is a single line input.

```
<input type="text" value="...">
```

A "textarea" will not, as it benefits from multi-line capabilities. Submitting on enter takes away some of this benefit.

```
<textarea name="area"></textarea>
```

You can add JavaScript code to detect the enter keypress and auto-submit, but you may be better off using a text input.

Comment: Because I want a multiline input box and I want the user to be able to submit by pressing enter. I am going to completely do away with the submit button. I think that SO should get rid of their Add Comment button if they are going to allow the comment to be submited when the enter key is pressed