# Execute on enter-key-press

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<script>
function cA( url )
{
    document.myform.action = url;
}
</script>

<input type="whatever" name="whatever" id="whatever" />                        
<button class="whatever-button" id="defaultAction" value="Go for it" name="whatever" type="submit" onClick="cA('whatever.php#anchor')" >Go for it                                                                                             
</button>
```

When you click the Go for it-Button, `whatever.php#anchor` is being loaded. How do I need to change the input tag's elements for it to execute the same `cA('whatever.php#anchor')` as the button click?

So when a user presses enter in the field, the site `whatever.php#anchor` should be loaded or more specifically, `cA('whatever.php#anchor')` be executed.

The page has more buttons, so making one button the default button does not work.

PS:

Wrapping all in one form does not work as the page's structure is

```
<form>
    <script>
    function cA( url )
    {
        document.myform.action = url;
    }
    </script>

    <input type="whatever1" name="whatever1" id="whatever1" />                        
    <button class="whatever1-button" id="defaultAction1" value="Go for it" name="whatever1" type="submit" onClick="cA('whatever.php#anchor1')" >Go for it                                                                                             
    </button> 

    <input type="whatever2" name="whatever2" id="whatever2" />                        
    <button class="whatever2-button2" id="defaultAction2" value="Go for it" name="whatever2" type="submit" onClick="cA('whatever.php#anchor2')" >Go for it                                                                                             
    </button> 

    <input type="whatever3" name="whatever3" id="whatever3" />                        
    <button class="whatever3-button" id="defaultAction3" value="Go for it" name="whatever3" type="submit" onClick="cA('whatever.php#anchor3')" >Go for it                                                                                             
    </button> 
    ...        
</form>
```

Comment: Warp this into a `<form>` and use the `onsubmit` event

Comment: @Brewal I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<input type="whatever" name="whatever" id="whatever" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {cA('whatever.php#anchor');}" />
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418819/submit-form-on-enter-when-in-text-field) post for more information.

Comment: Ah, thank you for noticing! I added it so the code is correct.

Comment: I tried your code (with quotation mark) but it jumps to `whatever.php#anchor1` even though I entered it in input `whatever2`

Comment: Hmm, I tried it but that doesn't happen to me. Still you can double-check the element by adding "event.srcElement.id == 'whatever'" to your if statement.

Comment: I replaced it with `onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {alert('Hello');}"`. The box appears but then the page reloads anyway. How do I disable this automatic behaviour?

Comment: You need to stop the form from submitting. This can be done by adding `event.preventDefault();`. You could also remove the form.

Comment: please include this in my example

Comment: Just like this: `<input type="whatever" name="whatever" id="whatever" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {event.preventDefault(); alert('Hello');}" />` EDIT: I added it inside the if, otherwise you cant type anymore.