# Submit form on press ENTER key event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form>   
  <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteID" value="#{myBean.item}"  
                       completeMethod="#{myBean.completeMethod}">   
  </p:autoComplete>
  <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.searchRelatedItems}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here my scenario is like Google search, I can see related Items in suggestion and also redirect another page based on text typed in `p:autoComplete` text field. Its works fine by clicking the button, but I also want to achieve the same by hitting `ENTER` in `p:autoComplete` text field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form on enter when in text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418819/submit-form-on-enter-when-in-text-field)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I believe the title should contain "Primefaces autocomplete" as this is no regular form submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [defaultCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml)

```
<h:form>   
  <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteID" value="#{myBean.item}"  
                       completeMethod="#{myBean.completeMethod}"    
  </p:autoComplete>
  <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{myBean.searchRelatedItems}"/>
  <p:defaultCommand target="#{myBean.btn}" />
</h:form>
```

and in your bean, a property with getter/setters idicating a button to be pressed on ENTER

```
 private String btn = "button";
```

Comment: It worked but for that i need to press ESC key before pressing ENTER key. It doesn't works when suggestion list is open, from auto complete.

Comment: Have you actualy resolved this issue? I just ran into it and it's pretty annoying. Pressing enter when the autocomplete overlay is up does nothing unless you select an item which I don't want to. All I want for the autocomplete to behave like Google search.

Comment: Using onkeypress and checking for enter key doesn't work either. The autocomplete overlay is most likely eating all the keyboard input.